# Image in Gallery not shown

Tags: android, image, android-intent, gallery

My app has tabs and one of it contains buttons to call the system gallery. I am able to access the gallery and folder, but when I want to display an image by clicking on it, the gallery disappears and returns me to my app.

This is my code:

```
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
```

May I know how to go about display the image? Thanks all in advance!

This is what I get when I launch gallery using the button and the images are in there but I am unable to launch and view the image on my phone.

[image: gallery]
[image]

Comment: Please give more of a description of what is happening. Do no images show up, do you have any images on the SD card? Do you step through it to ensure nothing odd is causing this?

Comment: I have images in the gallery and album. When I click on the image to display it, it returns me back to my app.

Answer (score 1):

Have you implemented onActvityResult method, on activityResult you need to fetch data from intent, and need to display image from this data, data contain imagepath.

Comment: Sorry, but how do I go about doing that? I have tried onActivityResult earlier on but it doesn't work still. Because my tab has 2 buttons. So how do I go about implementing onActivityResult?

Comment: You should really read the documentation before blindly using something like onActivityResult(xx).

Comment: you wont get any result from any activity even you start activity from onActivityResult method unless you dont implement onActivityResult implement your onActivityResult, and if you are facing any issue, then describe error, with your code.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't get what you mean. The issue I am facing is, I am trying to use the system gallery and I want the system gallery to have control of everything, which includes showing the albums/displaying the image. Now the issue is that I am unable to display the image, but I am able to launch the gallery even without using onActivityResult, and I am very confused with that.

Comment: see your code line Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK); this intent is used to pick an image from gallery

Comment: I know it is used to pick an image from gallery... So meaning I have to display the image that I have picked from the gallery? If so, how am I supposed to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Read this documentation to learn how to implement on onActivityResult(xx)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: But I don't think my problem lies with onActivityResult. I am able to go to the gallery, and view the folders/albums, but when I want to launch the image, the gallery stops and return me to my app. I have added the image of what I have gotten when testing to my original post

Comment: You said you haven't implemented it, you **MUST** implement it.

Comment: But without implementing onActivityResult, I am able to launch the system gallery. So what's happening?

Comment: doesn't mean that its right... you have to implement it to receive the data from the intent.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the intent need onActivityResult method. It is a little late, but if you need the answer you can do this

```
final static int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURED = 1;
private Uri uriImage;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURED) {
                uriImage = data.getData();
                Toast.makeText(MyClass.this, uriImage.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // Your code
            }
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            uriImage = null;
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Good Luck!